# Django 3.1 not serving media files correctly

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a project running in Django 3.1, and suddenly it has started to fail serving media files (static files uploaded by users), even though I haven't changed anything in settings.py or elsewhere.

My main urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
    path('', include('contacts.urls', namespace='contacts')),
    path('customers/', include('customers.urls', namespace='customers')),
    path('orders/', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
    path('account/', include('account.urls')),
    path('', include('catalog.urls', namespace='catalog')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

From my settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath( os.path.join(__file__, os.pardir))))
DEBUG = True
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join('static'), )

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

I don't know and can't figure out where the mistake is, but runserver just keeps throwing 404 when trying to load media files, even though static files (CSS/JS) are being served correctly.

Comment: Are the files present in the BASE_DIR/media/ directory?

Comment: Yes. I checked that they were there, and they have been all the time. They were served just correctly the last time I started the dev server,

Comment: Did you fix it? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

your Urls looks fine, although i notes that you missing `from django.contrib import admin`.
About your settings, here is mine that works just fine for me.
[image]

Add `import os` to your `settings.py` if it is not there.